# Any Good Number Picker for JQuery (or Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Are there any good number picker for jquery (or standalone js)?

I would like a number picker where there is a max and min number that the user can choose from. Also, it have other options such as displaying odd number or even number or prime number or a range of number whereby some numbers in between are skipped.

Comment: fyi, jquery ui 1.9 will have a spinner.

Comment: Why not use a select instead of a text box with a number picker?

Comment: @MiloLaMar Hi Milo, I wish I could but may I know how do you handle a range of number from 800000000 to 900000000 and in between these two number, some numbers need to be skipped, inside a `select`?

Comment: What do you mean by a "number picker"?  That term doesn't really mean anything in this context.  How do you expect to "pick" the number?  Do you mean a calculator type interface?  A slider bar? randomly picking a number out of thin air?  when someone says something picker, they mean a popup that allows selection from a group of items.  Like a color picker, or a date picker.  I can't seem to fathom what you're referring to here.

Comment: @MystereMan Hi Mystere, A "number picker" is a picker where you pick numbers. Color picker is a picker where you pick color while date picker is a picker where you pick date. As for the interface, I am ok with anything as long as it have options as describe in my question.

Comment: It sounds like your range is far too large to put in a select or any graphical interface, you just need a numeric validator of some sort I think.

Comment: @AndersonKaru - So you really don't know what you mean?  How do you propose "picking" a number?  What mechanism does this entail?  A dropdown list could be a "number picker" based on what you say.  But you have already said that's not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `select` to do this you can create an array with the numbers to skip and do a `for` loop to write the `options`:

```
int minNumber = 0;
int maxNumber = 10;

int[] skipThese = { 5, 7 };

for (int i = minNumber; i <= maxNumber; i++)
{
    if(!skipThese.Contains(i)) Response.Write(String.Concat("<option value=\"", i, "\">", i, "</option>"));
}
```

You can do this with razor or any other way to output the HTML.

You can also do this with jQuery, dynamicaly, following the same idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var minNumber = 0;
    var maxNumber = 10;

    var skipThese = [5, 7];

    for (var i = minNumber; i <= maxNumber; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(i, skipThese) == -1) $('#selectListID').append("<option value=\"" + i + "\">" + i + "</option>");
    }
});
```

Edit:
Or you can use the C# code above in an aspx page and load it with AJAX from the page:

Create a select box in the page:

```
<select name="numPicker" id="numPicker">
    <option>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

In a script in this page you could use jQuery's `ajax()` to fetch the data and populate the `<select>`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numPickerSelect = $("#numPicker");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url/to/page.aspx',
        type: 'post'
        success: function(data) {
            numPickerSelect.find('option').remove(); // Remove the options in the select field
            numPickerSelect.append(data); // Load the content generated by the server into the select field
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('An error has ocurred!');
        }
    });
    //Or use this (not sure if will work)
    numPickerSelect.load("url/to/page.aspx");
});
```

Comment: Marked as correct answer. Tested your code and working fine. However, the drop-down list will have a problem in future if a huge set of numbers are insert into the drop-down list - like `maxNumber = 90000`.

Comment: Sure. If it can reach this high, I recomend processing it in the server side and loading it with ajax. Drop a comment if you want some example code.

Comment: sure, would appreciate if you can drop some example code. If useful & helpful, I don't mind adding extra upvote to show my appreciation :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used this. You should be able to modify to add extra options such as min and max fairly easily.

```
// Make a control only accept numeric input
// eg, $("#myedit").numeric()
//  $("#myedit").numeric({alow: ' ,.'})
//  $("#myedit").numeric({decimals: 2})

(function($) {

    $.fn.alphanumeric = function(p) {

        if (p == 'destroy') {
            $(this).unbind('keypress');
            $(this).unbind('blur');
            return;
        }

        p = $.extend({
            ichars: "!@#$%^&*()+=[]\\\';,/{}|\":<>?~`.- ",
            nchars: "",
            allow: "",
            decimals: null
        }, p);

        return this.each
            (
                function() {

                    if (p.nocaps) p.nchars += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                    if (p.allcaps) p.nchars += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

                    s = p.allow.split('');
                    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) if (p.ichars.indexOf(s[i]) != -1) s[i] = "\\" + s[i];
                    p.allow = s.join('|');

                    var reg = new RegExp(p.allow, 'gi');
                    var ch = p.ichars + p.nchars;
                    ch = ch.replace(reg, '');

                    var dp = p.decimals;

                    var isInteger = function(val) {
                        var objRegExp = /(^-?\d\d*$)/;
                        return objRegExp.test(val);
                    };

                    var isNumeric = function(val) {
                        // If the last digit is a . then add a 0 before testing so if they type 25. it will be accepted
                        var lastChar = val.substring(val.length - 1);
                        if (lastChar == ".") val = val + "0";

                        var objRegExp = new RegExp("^\\s*-?(\\d+(\\.\\d{1," + dp + "})?|\\.\\d{1," + dp + "})\\s*$", "g");
                        if (dp == -1)
                            objRegExp = new RegExp("^\\s*-?(\\d+(\\.\\d{1,25})?|\\.\\d{1,25})\\s*$", "g");

                        var result = objRegExp.test(val);
                        return result;
                    };
                    $(this).blur(function(e) {
                        var text = $(this).val();
                        if (dp != null) {
                            if (dp == 0) {
                                if (!isInteger(text)) {
                                    $(this).val('');
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if (!isNumeric(text)) {
                                    $(this).val('');
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            var c = text.split('')
                            for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                                if (ch.indexOf(c[i]) != -1) {
                                    $(this).val('');
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).keypress
                        (
                            function(e) {

                                switch (e.which) {
                                    //Firefox fix, for ignoring specific presses             
                                    case 8: // backspace key
                                        return true;
                                    case 46: // delete key
                                        return true;
                                };

                                if (dp != null) {

                                    if (e.which == 32) { e.preventDefault(); return false; }

                                    var range = getRange(this);
                                    var typed = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                                    var text = $(this).val().substr(0, range.start) + typed + $(this).val().substr(range.start);

                                    if (dp == 0) {
                                        if (!isInteger(text)) e.preventDefault();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        if (!isNumeric(text)) e.preventDefault();
                                    }
                                    return;
                                }

                                if (!e.charCode) k = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                                else k = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);

                                if (ch.indexOf(k) != -1) e.preventDefault();
                                if (e.ctrlKey && k == 'v') e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        );

                    $(this).bind('contextmenu', function() { return false });

                }
            );

    };

    $.fn.numeric = function(p) {

        if (p == 'destroy') {
            $(this).unbind('keypress');
            $(this).unbind('blur');
            return;
        }
        var az = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        az += az.toUpperCase();

        var opts = {};

        if (!isNaN(p)) {
            opts = $.extend({
                nchars: az
            }, { decimals: p });
        } else {
            opts = $.extend({
                nchars: az
            }, p);
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).alphanumeric(opts);
        }
        );

    };

    $.fn.integer = function(p) {

        if (p == 'destroy') {
            $(this).unbind('keypress');
            $(this).unbind('blur');
            return;
        }

        var az = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        az += az.toUpperCase();

        p = {
            nchars: az,
            allow: '-',
            decimals: 0
        };

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).alphanumeric(p);
        }
        );
    };

    $.fn.alpha = function(p) {

        if (p == 'destroy') {
            $(this).unbind('keypress');
            $(this).unbind('blur');
            return;
        }
        var nm = "1234567890";

        p = $.extend({
            nchars: nm
        }, p);

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).alphanumeric(p);
        }
        );

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 Very comprehensive and massive coding. All I hope that I know how to use your code to make my thing work.